# How to configure active directory in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, administrator, active-directory

I just installed Remote Server Administrative Tools (RSAT) on windows 7, and turned features on as mentioned in the installation guide. Now the Administrative Tools have been installed and successfully listed in the *All Programs* list of start menu.

I want to set up a local network. I want to create users/passwords, and give them access to shared drives with permissions, etc.

My questions is:

***How do I configure the Active Directory in windows 7 for the first time?***

***Edit 1***

If Active Directory is not for windows 7, why has Microsoft provided RSAT for windows 7? (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887)

Answer (score 3):

As its name says, they are intenteded for a Remote Server Administration, so you need a Windows Server (it can be a VM) to create an Active Directory.

It's like you just installed the steering wheel but not the car...

Comment: If Windows Server is unavailable, there's always Samba 4 on Linux.

Comment: Thanks @Santeador for your answer. But if Active Directory is not for windows 7, why has Microsoft provided RSAT for windows 7? (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887)

Comment: Because you can manage it from Windows 7 with that package installed. If not, you need to make a RDP connection to the server or, nowadays, learn Powershell.